# Session ID changes in every AJAX request

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, session, session-cookies

I've developed a e-commerce site with PHP, MySQL, and AJAX.

The code works fine [here](http://www.nazrulkabir.com/boidokan).
But [here](http://www.boidokan.com), every time I click "add to cart" it creates a different session ID.

I've tried both of these, but neither works:

```
@ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 30*60);
@ini_set('session.cookie_secure','On');
```

Also, `session.auto_start` is OFF.

PHP info can be found [here](http://www.boidokan.com/info.php).

Comment: check your cookie timeout, and if cookie enabled.

Comment: Also check that you have a `session_start()` before you use any sessions in your code, and aren't relying on `session.auto_start` on the other sites. Btw, your screenshot didn't make it into your question.

Comment: How to check cookie timeout?

Comment: session.auto_start is off check here: http://www.boidokan.com/info.php

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite an old question but I recently came across this issue today and solved it by placing a check if the SESSION variable is already set. So, if the variable that you use for checks is `$_SESSION['id']` then, you can probably do the following:

```
   if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])){ //Checks if id is empty
      $_SESSION['id'] = 'some_unique_id'; //If empty, then create a new one
   }
```